# What to assign for MySQL column that must not be empty?

Tags: mysql, database, null, relational-database, ddl

I have a MySQL table named `customers`. In this table, there is a column called `fullname` that must not be empty when a new row is created. Is it right to assign a `Not Null` attribute to this column to imply that the column cannot be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It a word - yes. If a column may not be empty, it should be defined as `not null`.

Comment: Way to get to 30 characters ... ;)